# How is it possible to call a report in J D Edwards via Dell Boomi?

Tags: jdedwards, boomi

I want to call  a report in JD Edwards via Dell Boomi. I have already established the database. Can you help me with it?

Answer (score 1):

You can call JD Edwards report using following AIS REST report service API from Dell Boomi

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53430_01/EOTRS/api-report-service.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Boomi, however something like runubxml can trigger reports remotely.
there is documentation on Oracle site about configuring this in JDE.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to call the JDE report, create published business web service(BSSV) then call that web service from dell boomi.
Published BSSV internally call the JDE report using the C BSFN.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by calling REST API from Boomi through LynX Business Integrator: http://aellius.com/lynx-business-integrator

Answer (score 0):

Dell Bhoomi should be able to connect with AIS, later you can send required UBE detail through XML document to AIS server, and from AIS server detail can be pass to Scheduler (not JDE scheduler but AIS), that is how you can complete this integration. in case you want to perform transection outside JDE via AIS then you can call BSFN (business function ) B98ORCH from JDE end which can perform outbound transaction (from JDE to outside JDE ).